# Get a value and than use that value to compare

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-5.0

I am facing a problem with a PowerShell variable.

My scenario is,

- Inside a function, I declare a variable `$a`, than in a switch, I get a value and store this to variable `$a`.
- Now in another switch in that function, I want to compare `$a`. But there `$a` returns null.

Sample code is given below:

```
function fun 
{

  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    $param       
   )

    $Get_OldData = " " #declare variable

    switch ($param){

        'param_001' {
            $Get_OldData = "test data returned"
        }

        Default {
            $Get_OldData = "test data returned"
        }
    }


    switch ($param){

        'param_001' {
            $New_Data = "New Data"

            #problem is here, can not compare $Get-OldData returns null here
            #though data is assigned 

            if ( $New_Data  -eq $Get_OldData){
                #logic goes here
            }
        }
        Default {
            $New_Data = "New Data"
        }
    }
}
```

What is the solution of this problem?

Comment: Are you sure about `$New-Data`? It looks like it should use underscore instead of dash.

Comment: @vonPryz i just made typing mistake

Answer (score 1):

You have *multiple* issues with your code.

The main issue probably is that you are using `$param` within your switch which has not been set. Same applies to `$Fetch`. Another Issue is that your `$New-Data` variable contains a hypen which you either should *replace with an underscore* or *surround with curly brackets* like `${New-Data}`.

Also, `//` does not introduce a comment, you have to use a hash `#`.

Comment: thanks but $param is set properly and $New-Data is $New_Data which is typo mistake

Comment: where do you set `$param` and `$Fetch`?

Comment: actually, this function has a parameter and $param is passed through that....i don't add this in my code for to save time.same for $fetch

Comment: You should provide a reproducable peace of code, not a snippet with a lot of mistakes where you omit main parts of the function. You don't save us time with that - quite the opposite

Comment: If I cleanup all your mistakes, the code works as expected. So I am voting to close this question.

Comment: first, get the old value than set the new one and compare with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134344/discussion-between-eric-ipsum-and-martin-brandl).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion  ..... i solved it by my own way...but as its not the actual answer, i don't mark it as answer. only upvoted